# How to set an event listener for the animation end event

Tags: javascript, animation, event-listener

Instead of setting a time out, I want to set an event listener for the animation end event.

Where the function will be executed as soon as the animation completes without needing the extra timer.

To do that, I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event

But I don't know how that would be written into my code. https://jsfiddle.net/7yn9ofk8/

As I understand it, I need to add an event listener to the body and listen for `animationend`, inside the callback run the code I am running inside `setTimeout`.

How would that be added to the code?

The fadeOut occurs after clicking the Exit button, which can be seen after clicking the play svg.

I provided a snippet where the fadeOut is viewable.

**CSS**

```
.fadingOut:before,
.fadingOut .isOpen {
  animation: fadingOut 1s;
}

@keyframes fadingOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
  function resetPage() {
    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("fadingOut");
    setTimeout(function() {

      document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("fadingOut");
      resetBackground("body");
      resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
      showAllButtons(".container.hide");
      resetButtons(".outer");
    }, 1000);
  }
```

```js
const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

    function showBackground(background) {
      background.classList.remove("bg1");
    }
    allBackgrounds.forEach(showBackground);
  }

  function resetCurtains(curtainSelector) {
    const allCurtains = document.querySelectorAll(curtainSelector);

    function showCurtain(curtain) {
      curtain.classList.remove("active");
    }
    allCurtains.forEach(showCurtain);
  }

  function showAllButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function showButton(button) {
      button.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(showButton);
  }

  function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function showButton(button) {
      button.classList.remove("isOpen");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(showButton);
  }

  function resetPage() {
    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("fadingOut");
    setTimeout(function () {

      document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("fadingOut");
      resetBackground("body");
      resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
      showAllButtons(".container.hide");
      resetButtons(".outer");
    }, 1000);
  }

  function hideCurtains(exitButtons) {
    const container = exitButtons.closest(".inner-container");
    const curtains = container.querySelector(".sliding-panels");
    curtains.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function exitClickHandler(evt) {
    resetPage();
    hideCurtains(evt.currentTarget);
  }

  function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
    exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
      exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    addClickToExit(exitButtons);
  }

  return {
    init
  };
}());

const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

    function hideBackground(background) {
      background.classList.add("bg1");
    }
    allBackgrounds.forEach(hideBackground);
  }

  function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function hideButton(button) {
      button.classList.add("isOpen");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(hideButton);
  }

  function resetPage() {
    resetBackground("body");
    resetButtons(".outer");
  }

  function markAsPlayed(played) {
    played.classList.add("played");
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    resetPage();
    markAsPlayed(evt.currentTarget);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function createResetHandler(player) {
    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      video.addEventListener("click", function resetVideoHandler() {
        player.destroy();
      });
    })
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    createResetHandler(player);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    return player;
  }

  function addPlayer(video, playerOptions) {
    playerOptions.videoId = playerOptions.videoId || video.dataset.id;
    playerOptions.events = playerOptions.events || {};
    playerOptions.events.onReady = onPlayerReady;
    playerOptions.events.onStateChange = onPlayerStateChange;

    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const playerVars = {
    autoplay: 1,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    enablejsapi: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3
  };
  const defaults = {
    height: 360,
    host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
    playerVars,
    width: 640
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function combinePlayerOptions(opts1 = {}, opts2 = {}) {
    const combined = Object.assign({}, opts1, opts2);
    Object.keys(opts1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
      if (typeof opts1[prop] === "object") {
        combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, opts1[prop], opts2[prop]);
      }
    });
    return combined;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, playerOptions = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const options = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, playerOptions);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, options);
  }

  function createCallback(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    return function callback() {
      initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    };
  }

  function playerAdder(parent, playerOptions) {
    const wrapper = parent.querySelector(".wrap");
    return function callback() {
      initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    };
  }

  function initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    show(wrapper);
    const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    wrapper.player = player;
  }

  return {
    adder: playerAdder,
    createCallback
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerOptions) {
    const parent = document.querySelector(coverSelector).parentElement;
    const callback = managePlayer.adder(parent, playerOptions);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, callback);
  }

  addPlayer(".playa", {});
  addPlayer(".playb", {});
  addPlayer(".playc", {});
  addPlayer(".playd", {});
  addPlayer(".playe", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
    }
  });
  addPlayer(".playf", {});
  addPlayer(".playg", {});
  addPlayer(".playh", {});
  addPlayer(".playi", {});

  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });

  manageUI.init({});
}
```

```css
.play1  {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play2 {
  --color-a: purple;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: purple;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play3 {
  --color-a: green;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: green;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play4 {
  --color-a: orange;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: orange;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play5 {
  --color-a: yellow;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: yellow;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play6 {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: orange;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play7 {
  --color-a: red;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: green;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play8 {
  --color-a: white;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: white;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play9 {
  --color-a: red;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadingOut:before,
.fadingOut .isOpen {
  animation: fadingOut 1s;
}

@keyframes fadingOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 290px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

.outer.isOpen {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

body.bg1 {
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
}

body.bg1 .with-curtain:before{
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.thePlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.thePlay:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.thePlay {

  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  fill: blue;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.played {
  fill: green;
}



button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  fill: red;
  padding: 0;
}

.exitsvg {
  fill: none;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-width: 17.80202103;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  border: 4.625px solid #4e4e4e;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain3 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain4 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain4 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain5 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain5 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain6 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain6 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain7 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain7 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain8 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain8 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain9 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain9 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="container play1 with-curtain">
        <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <g id="play">
          <title>Play</title>
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
          <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                  M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sliding-panels">
                    <div class="panel-left"></div>
                    <div class="panel-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path d="M 6.3895625,6.4195626 C 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437" />
            <path d="M 6.3894001,93.6106 C 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container play2 with-curtain">
        <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sliding-panels">
                    <div class="panel-left"></div>
                    <div class="panel-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container play3 with-curtain">
        <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sliding-panels">
                    <div class="panel-left"></div>
                    <div class="panel-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container play4 with-curtain">
        <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain4">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sliding-panels">
                    <div class="panel-left"></div>
                    <div class="panel-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container play5 with-curtain">
        <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain5">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sliding-panels">
                    <div class="panel-left"></div>
                    <div class="panel-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container play6 with-curtain">
        <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain6">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sliding-panels">
                    <div class="panel-left"></div>
                    <div class="panel-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container play7 with-curtain">
        <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain7">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sliding-panels">
                    <div class="panel-left"></div>
                    <div class="panel-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container play8 with-curtain">
        <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain8">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sliding-panels">
                    <div class="panel-left"></div>
                    <div class="panel-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container play9 with-curtain">
        <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain9">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sliding-panels">
                    <div class="panel-left"></div>
                    <div class="panel-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it, I need to add an event listener to the body and
> listen for `animationend`, inside the callback run the code I am running
> inside `setTimeout`.

You have everything right.

You'll need to use another `addEventListener()` (as you have used elsewhere).

The implementation looks like this:

```
function resetPage() {

  document.body.classList.add("fadingOut");
  document.body.addEventListener('animationend', function() {

      document.body.classList.remove("fadingOut");
      resetBackground("body");
      resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
      showAllButtons(".container.hide");
      resetButtons(".outer");
    });
}
```

**N.B.** You don't need `document.querySelector('head')` or `document.querySelector('body')`. Instead, `document.head` and `document.body` are standard.